# Maven dependency not in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a project which uses spring. It uses version 3.1.1 but, for some reason I really don't know, some spring artifacts are duplicated with two different versions. I look for the those dependencies in all pom.xml files from my project. I also use the dependecy plugin to figure out where were those dependencies included.

Here you have an extract of the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
```

As far as I know this means that `org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile` is included in `org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile`.

I workaround this including a dependency with scope `provided` but I'd need to know why is this happening.

**Update**:
It seems that when I comment the next code the jars are not included in the war.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf-version}</version>
</dependency>
...
<properties>
    ...
    <cxf-version>2.4.2</cxf-version>
    <spring.version>3.1.1</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: I can't really believe that both versions are actually on the classpath if its the exact same dependency with the same artifact and groupId. Maven should manage that and only include one. So far, it all looks like expected behavior and you're trying to fix a problem that is not really a problem.

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to get more info on whether it is actually included or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `spring-context` [pom](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.pom) defines the dependency to `spring-core` with exact the same version as the `spring-context`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thus you must have a `dependencyManagement` somewhere in your project that tells maven to use `3.0.5.RELEASE` instead of `3.1.1.RELEASE`.

Take a look at your poms. There must be something like this in a `dependencyManagement`.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Depending on your maven version it might also be possible that you use [dependency import](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

PS: same for `spring-asm`

Comment: There are not any dependencyManagement

Answer (score 0):

If i add only the `org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE` to a project and show the tree via `mvn dependency:tree` the following output appears:

```
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
```

wher never got a reference to `org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE` or `org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE`. This means you have an other dependency which introduces that or you are using a dependencyManagement block overwrites that.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking for that dependency but I really don't see it.