# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jdbc, wildfly

I'm creating a simple Web app and decided to use a Spring JdbcTemplate class. But now I'm encountering the NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper .

According to the stack trace something is wrong with ControllerServlet on line 32. Which is:

```
productDAOImpl = new ProductDAOImpl(dataSource);
```

What may be the reason for the error? What should I do to fix it?

```
Context Path:/webstore_war_exploded
Servlet Path:/ControllerServlet
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper
com.ncproject.webstore.controller.ControllerServlet.init(ControllerServlet.java:32)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:171)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**ControllerServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet("/ControllerServlet")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ProductDAOImpl productDAOImpl;

@Resource(lookup = "java:/PostgresNC")
private DataSource dataSource;


@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    try {
        productDAOImpl = new ProductDAOImpl(dataSource);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new ServletException(exc);
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String theCommand = request.getParameter("command");

        if (theCommand == null) {
            theCommand = "PRODUCT_LIST";
        }

        switch (theCommand) {
            case "PRODUCT_LIST":
                listProducts(request, response);
                break;
            case "ADD_UPDATE":
                addOrUpdateProduct(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                listProducts(request, response);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void listProducts(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    List<Product> products = productDAOImpl.getAllProducts();

    request.setAttribute("PRODUCT_LIST", products);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/list-products.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

private void addOrUpdateProduct(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // read product from the form
    String idString = request.getParameter("productId");
    String category = request.getParameter("category");
    String description = request.getParameter("description");
    String productName = request.getParameter("productName");
    String price = request.getParameter("price");
    BigDecimal priceBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(price);
    String brand = request.getParameter("brand");

    try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idString.trim());
        int numCategory = Integer.parseInt(category);

        if(idString != null && category != null) {

            Product theProduct = new Product(id, numCategory, description, productName, priceBigDecimal, brand);

            // add the product to the database
            productDAOImpl.saveOrUpdate(theProduct);
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    listProducts(request, response);
}
```

**ProductDAOImpl.java**

```
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO {
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

//private DataSource dataSource;

public ProductDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Override
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY prod_id\n" +
            "ASC";
    List<Product> productList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Product>() {
        @Override
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Product theProduct = new Product();

            theProduct.setProd_id(resultSet.getInt("prod_id"));
            theProduct.setCategory(resultSet.getInt("category"));
            theProduct.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
            theProduct.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
            theProduct.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
            theProduct.setBrand("brand");

            return theProduct;
        }
    });
    return productList;
}

@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Product newProduct) {
    if (newProduct.getProd_id() > 0) {
        // update
        String sql = "UPDATE products "
                + "SET category=?, description=?, prod_name=?, price=?, brand=? "
                + "WHERE prod_id=?";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, newProduct.getCategory(), newProduct.getDescription(),
                newProduct.getProductName(), newProduct.getPrice(), newProduct.getBrand());
    } else {
        // insert
        String sql = "INSERT INTO products (prod_id, category, description, prod_name, price, brand) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, newProduct.getProd_id(), newProduct.getCategory(), newProduct.getDescription(),
                newProduct.getProductName(), newProduct.getPrice(), newProduct.getBrand());
    }
} }
```

Comment: The most possible reason for NoClassDefFoundError is 1) you have not package spring-jdbc jar file into your war file. 2) you have package it to the war file but your application server contains another spring-jdbc jar file that is of another version which is not compatible to your source code.

Answer (score 0):

The required JAR file isn't available, so what you need to do is to place it on your `CLASSPATH`.
You might choose to add the corresponding JAR file to your CLASSPATH, or as an alternate, you can download the JAR file from [here](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgspringframeworkjdbc300M2jar.htm).

A similar question on the same topic, for your reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327497/nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o).